# If $A$ and $B$ are row stochastic, so is $AB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I prove this problem:
If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices whose rows sum to $1$, show that the rows of $AB$ also sum to $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $v=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$. The condition that the rows of a matrix $M$ sum to $1$ is the same as saying that $Mv=v$. Since $Av=v$ and $Bv=v$, what does that tell you about $ABv$?